# Does Bot/BotFramework support authentication through certificate?

Tags: authentication, botframework

From the 'App Registration Portal' where manages the bot credential, it seems authentication through public/private certificates is supported, but I can't find any documentation on that, and in BotFramework source code on github, there's no clue it's supported.
So the question is:
1. Does BotFramwork support certificate authentication?
2. If no for #1, and I want to use certificate authentication, does BotConnector support it? If yes, any sample code?
3. If no for #2, is app id/password considered a secure way to let Bot access all business data? any plan to support certificate authentication in the future version?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by secure?  It can easily be interpreted many different ways.

Comment: You're right, maybe the question should be which level of security id/password brings compared to certificate-based auth? At least by using certificate it's asymmetric?